# Pattern Day Trade - $25,000 Margin Account Rule

Tags: united-states, stock-markets, day-trading

I am kind of new to day trading stocks. I was just a bit confused regarding the pattern day trade rule which prevents people with under $25,000 to exceed 3 day trades per week.

**Does the $25,000 have to be in cash or does it also include the margin which the brokerage firm offers?**

Assuming it all has to be my cash not margin, I would like to present a situations and would love to know your opinion:

I ran out of 3 day trades and on my 4th trade of the week I buy 24,000 worth of stocks with my cash and sell them at 25,000, because I am > 25,000 will they remove my previous 3 day trades flag and reset it to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $25,000 amount is for equity in your brokerage account (cash and investments).  It does not include any margin amount that has been loaned to you.

To answer your second question, I think you are misunderstanding the concepts behind the pattern day trader rules.  Your brokerage account is either considered a "pattern day trader" or it is not.  Once you are flagged as a pattern day trader, you will be required to maintain this $25,000 equity amount or you will not be allowed to trade.

You are flagged as a pattern day trader [as soon as you day trade a fourth time](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/73195/10997) in any 5-day period.  It doesn't matter what your equity happens to be during that period.  And once you are flagged as a pattern day trader, you will be required to maintain that $25,000 equity amount indefinitely.

You should study the page that FINRA put together about day-trading:

[Day-Trading Margin Requirements - Know the Rules](http://www.finra.org/investors/day-trading-margin-requirements-know-rules)

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much. Thank's for sharing the link it went over many of the questions I forgot to ask.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement is [equity](http://www.finra.org/investors/day-trading-margin-requirements-know-rules), meaning it does not include your margin.